# Matlab: How can I change a push button's property in the other function?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I had created a guide GUI and i need to change one of the push button's color in the other function. my friend told me if not using GUIDE GUI then only global the push button at both side. but it is not work in guide GUI. Any one can tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `global` variables, you can also access it through `handles` (if you are using GUIDE).

```
 function myCallback(hObj,evt,handles)
      data = get(handles.myOtherPushButton);
      disp(data);
 end
```

Comment: It works even without using GUIDE actually : just create your main figure with `ha.f=figure(...)` (ha means handles but call it as you wish) and then create each button with `ha.button1=uicontrol('Style','Pushbutton','Parent',ha.f,...)` and then use `guidata(ha.f,ha)` and also `ha=guidata(ha.f)`as with GUIDE. :)
Then change a button value with `set(ha.button1,'Value',1)` for instance.